# Jump back to right page in paginator

Tags: php, mysql

I have a paginator in my page, which lists several items per page which are editable.
If someone decides to edit an item, they are send to a url like /edit/12.
Now when they click 'cancel' on that page I would like to send them back to the right page.

What query would I need to do this? I'm using MySQL. I'm hoping for a solution where I don't have get all the rows from the table, but I'm afraid it's not possible without doing so..

Comment: Why not using JavaScript and `history.back();` ?

Comment: I have that now, but if they have edited the item, the item is saved and the user is shown the edit screen again. The back button is also there and would go to the first step of the edit action..

Answer (score 0):

Put this as onclick event on the cancel button:

```
window.history.back(); return false;
```

Functions like the back button in your browser.

Comment: see my comment to the first question

Comment: I see, then you'd have to go with a session or another GET parameter (if you really want to avoid another query).

Comment: well a query is ok, but normally with paginating you can limit because you know the page, I'm afraid the only query that would work here is one that gets the whole table, finds the position of the item and then figures out the page

Comment: check this mysql function out: [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows).

Answer (score 0):

Is the pagination URL based? If so, can you hang on to that somewhere, like a $_SESSION var or even passing it along in the $_GET vars and the re-use it after editing?

Comment: yeah I have that as my possible work around indeed, but being the nitpick I am, I'm afraid of cases where someone else would have added items to the table, and the offset would be wrong. So in my ideal case I'd add this logic to the routing; first decide where the cancelled item is in the stack and then redirect to the right page

Answer (score 0):

First workaround would be to use

```
javascript:history.back(-1 - number_of_saves_in_this_session);
```

instead of `history.back()`. But this requires to keep number of saves in session.

Proper way, efficient variant, requires you to have records ordered by some unique key, like id.

So lets say you have 25 records (id 1-25) ordered by descending id, limited to 10 on page (1st page - id 25-16, page 2 id 15-6, page 3 id 5-1)

what you need is number of records before your id, you can get this with:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS number_of_records FROM table WHERE id > 12
```

Now add some basic math to calculate which page it is

```
SELECT FLOOR(COUNT(id)/10) AS desired_page FROM table WHERE id > 12
```

Multiply it by 10 and you have ready to use `OFFSET` for mysql query.

Most tricky case is if you have more complicated sorting. The main idea is like above, get number of records before the one you have edited. You can get only id's into php array and get index for edited id or use temp table and auxiliary variable in mysql:

```
SET @i=0;
SELECT FLOOR((`position`-1)/10) AS desired_page FROM (
    SELECT @i:=@i+1 AS position, `id` FROM `table` ORDER BY `name`, `date`, `other`, `other2` 
) tmp_tbl
WHERE `id` = 12
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you use a flag to tell the app which page you are coming from. You can just add the actual page to the edit/add url just like /edit/12/p:1 then when you cancel it, just link to main/p:1

Comment: why i get a negative vote? check their comment "I have that now, but if they have edited the item, the item is saved and the user is shown the edit screen again. The back button is also there and would go to the first step of the edit action.. – Maarten" he actually have a js but when it save it, then he cant go back, isnt a bad practice to put the page number of the referer, can you at least give me a god reason?